# how to create unique batches for each label from tf.Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Let us assume that my data is as follows:

**feature, label**

vector1, 1

vector2, 1

vector3, 0

vector4, 1,

vector5, 0

I want to get a batch where it should represent a random 1 sample from each label for each iteration under the batch size condition such as  2. 
For example, for the first iteration, I can receive:

vector1, 1

vector3, 0

For example, for the second iteration, I can receive:

vector4, 1

vector5, 0

and so on...

Would you please lead me how to implement in an efficient way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would split the `Dataset` into two streams by using a `filter` on each label, then merge those streams back, for example by relying on `tf.contrib.data.choose_from_datasets`.

An advantage is that you don't loose any sample in the process (as opposed to the example you give).

A small example with toy data:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def gen():
  # generate random (value, label) pairs
  while True:
    yield (np.random.uniform(), np.random.randint(0, 2))

def split_and_merge(ds):
  return tf.contrib.data.choose_from_datasets(
    [ds.filter(lambda x, label: tf.equal(label, 0)),
     ds.filter(lambda x, label: tf.equal(label, 1))],
    tf.data.Dataset.range(2).repeat())

batch = (tf.data.Dataset
    .from_generator(gen, (tf.float32, tf.int32), (tf.TensorShape([]), tf.TensorShape([])))
    .apply(split_and_merge)
    .batch(2)
    .make_one_shot_iterator()
    .get_next())

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
for _ in range(5):
  sess.run(batch)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, do you think this solution would be expanded to the case where I have 1000+ labels?

Comment: In addition to that, I am having the following error `module tensorflow.contrib.data' has no attribute 'choose_from_datasets` for tf v. 1.8.0

Comment: Upgrading to tf v. 1.10 + solved the module error. On the other hand, I was able to run your code for the 1000+ labels. Unfortunately, It is very slow. How can we achieve the best case without having that kind of performance problem?

Comment: @TheWho It is hard to tell without further knowledge. I would try the usual recommended tricks first, like prefetching. Also, if you have the possibility to load the label first then the corresponding data, you will probably be faster by loading data after doing the `split_and_merge`.

Comment: It would be really great if I was able to learn how to receive unique samples without having the performance issue. Otherwise, even one epoch is completed in unreasonable long time :(